How to Suppress False Positives in MobSF Reports for Android Builds?
I'm using MobSF (Mobile Security Framework) to analyze the security of my Android application. While it works well, I'm encountering false positives in the generated reports, which are unfairly reducing the security score of my app.
I want to achieve the following:
Suppress specific false positives that I know are not actual vulnerabilities.
Ensure these suppressed findings do not appear in the generated PDF report.
Maintain an accurate security score that excludes these false positives.
Is there a configuration or method in MobSF that allows me to mark specific findings as false positives and exclude them from the reports? If not, are there alternative approaches to handle this scenario effectively?

Just making sure you are aware of: https://mobsf.github.io/docs/#/?id=mobsf-support
